# How do I run this JabRef JAR file I downloaded?

Tags: linux, java, jar

I downloaded a jar file from [here](https://www.fosshub.com/JabRef.html). But - I don't know how to get it to run. Here's the error I get:

```
$ java -jar /path/to/JabRef-4.1.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class org.jabref.JabRefMain
```

What am I doing wrong, or rather, what am I missing?

I'm running GNU/Linux Mint 18.3 on an x86_64 machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JabRef-4.1.jar` requires Oracle java. Works with java8. Example https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04

My example ...

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
$ sudo apt-get -f install
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: You actually don't have to change the default java binary...

Answer (score 1):

You've probably hit the [JDK9 compatibility issue](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/3054), which is a duplicate of [this issue](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/2594). Be sure to check if javafx/openjfx is installed or not, since that is another [possible cause](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/2867).